# Code not removing "\n" from json GET response

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, file, get

So I'm trying to remove a bunch of "\n" from a Json GET request. However, when I make a string copy of the response and try to .replace("\n", "") nothing gets removed

```
def fetchProxy():
    return urllib.request.urlopen("https://api.getproxylist.com/proxy").read()


def createList():
    afile = open("proxies.json", "a")

    i = 1
    for i in range(3):
        proxy = str((fetchProxy())).replace("\n","",-1)
        afile.write(proxy + "\n")
    afile.close()
```

This is all the code used to GET the json and put it into a file (3 times over). Also, pretty much all the code in the entire project at the moment.

Sample json:

```
b'{\n    "_links": {\n        "_self": "\/proxy",\n        "_parent":
"\/"\n    },\n    "ip": "177.23.106.107",\n    "port": 4145,\n
"protocol": "socks4",\n    "anonymity": "high anonymity",\n
"lastTested": "2019-02-23 23:53:48",\n    "allowsRefererHeader":
true,\n    "allowsUserAgentHeader": true,\n    "allowsCustomHeaders":
true,\n    "allowsCookies": true,\n    "allowsPost": true,\n
"allowsHttps": true,\n    "country": "BR",\n    "connectTime":
"0.692",\n    "downloadSpeed": "155.000",\n    "secondsToFirstByte":
"1.128",\n    "uptime": "45.621"\n}'
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a little trick to do it—basically a one-liner. Since newlines and other whitespace is generally ignored in JSON, you can take advantage of that and convert the `response` into a Python dictionary and then convert that back into JSON.

```
import json
import urllib.request


def fetchProxy():
    response = urllib.request.urlopen("https://api.getproxylist.com/proxy").read()
    return json.dumps(json.loads(response))  # Clean up.

def createList():
    proxy = fetchProxy()  # Only do it once.

    with open("proxies.json", "a") as file:
        for _ in range(3):
            file.write(proxy + "\n")


if __name__ == '__main__':

    createList()
```

Contents of `proxies.json` afterwards:

```
{"_links": {"_self": "/proxy", "_parent": "/"}, "ip": "177.66.42.126", "port": 4145, "protocol": "socks4", "anonymity": "high anonymity", "lastTested": "2019-02-27 12:43:02", "allowsRefererHeader": true, "allowsUserAgentHeader": true, "allowsCustomHeaders": true, "allowsCookies": true, "allowsPost": true, "allowsHttps": true, "country": "BR", "connectTime": "0.773", "downloadSpeed": "135.000", "secondsToFirstByte": "1.281", "uptime": "96.580"}
{"_links": {"_self": "/proxy", "_parent": "/"}, "ip": "177.66.42.126", "port": 4145, "protocol": "socks4", "anonymity": "high anonymity", "lastTested": "2019-02-27 12:43:02", "allowsRefererHeader": true, "allowsUserAgentHeader": true, "allowsCustomHeaders": true, "allowsCookies": true, "allowsPost": true, "allowsHttps": true, "country": "BR", "connectTime": "0.773", "downloadSpeed": "135.000", "secondsToFirstByte": "1.281", "uptime": "96.580"}
{"_links": {"_self": "/proxy", "_parent": "/"}, "ip": "177.66.42.126", "port": 4145, "protocol": "socks4", "anonymity": "high anonymity", "lastTested": "2019-02-27 12:43:02", "allowsRefererHeader": true, "allowsUserAgentHeader": true, "allowsCustomHeaders": true, "allowsCookies": true, "allowsPost": true, "allowsHttps": true, "country": "BR", "connectTime": "0.773", "downloadSpeed": "135.000", "secondsToFirstByte": "1.281", "uptime": "96.580"}
```

Answer (score 0):

This call:

```
    str((fetchProxy()))
```

Puts escape characters around \n.
You either want to call replace with

```
    proxy = str((fetchProxy())).replace("\\n","")
```

Or if you prefer to save the string value in the file and not the bytes:

```
    proxy = fetchProxy().decode().replace('\n', '')
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to do something like this, where the `.replace("\n", "")` is a variable (I am changing your first function to a variable, to make it usable in the second one, I hope this doesn't affect the wanted result):

```
fetchProxy= return urllib.request.urlopen("https://api.getproxylist.com/proxy").read()
fetchProxy=str(fetchProxy)
fetchProxy=fetchProxy.replace("\n", "")


def createList():
    afile = open("proxies.json", "a")

    i = 1
    for i in range(3):
        proxy = fetchProxy 
#str((fetchProxy())).replace("\n","",-1) 
#I am not sure why the last argument in the .replace is -1, because the last argument is number of 
#occurences to be replaced and default is all, if left empty
        afile.write(proxy + "\n")
    afile.close()
```